# Freeswitch bgapi originate command with ignore_early_media=true

Tags: freeswitch

I'm trying the following scenario on freeswitch:

- Create a call (a-leg)
- Create another call (b-leg)
- Bridge then together

The b-leg phone is a dial plan in other freeswitch is the following:

```
<extension name="EarlyMedia">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^[+]?[1]?<MY_NUMBER>">
        <action application="pre_answer"/>
        <action application="playback" data="/home/ubuntu/EARLY_MEDIA.wav"/>
        <action application="sleep" data="1000"/>
        <action application="answer"/>
        <action application="playback" data="/home/ubuntu/CALL_MEDIA.wav"/>
        <action application="sleep" data="1000"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

The sequence of commands that i sent to freeswitch is the following:

- a-leg

`bgapi originate {ignore_early_media=true,bridge_early_media=false,origination_caller_id_number=sofia/external/<MY_FROM_NUMBER>@<MY_IP>,origination_channel_name=<MY_CHANNEL>,ringback=\'%(2000,4000,440,480)\'}sofia/external/<A-LEG NUMBER>@<MY_IP> &park()`

- b-leg

`bgapi originate {ignore_early_media=true,bridge_early_media=false,origination_caller_id_number=sofia/external/<MY_FROM_NUMBER>@<MY_IP>,origination_channel_name=<MY_CHANNEL>,ringback=\'%(2000,4000,440,480)\'}sofia/external/<B-LEG NUMBER>@<MY_IP> &park()`

- uuid_bridge

`bgapi uuid_bridge <A-LEG UUID> <B-LEG UUID>`

The problem is that even with **ignore_early_media=true,bridge_early_media=false** i hear the early media on A-LEG

Answer (score 0):

`ignore_early_media` does not mean you do not 'hear' the early media. It just means Freeswitch will not treat it as an answer.

From [the docs](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/ignore_early_media) `ignore_early_media`:

> Controls if the call returns on early media or not. Default is false

Even with `ringback=\'%(2000,4000,440,480)\` set, I have found that Freeswitch will still send a [183 SIP response](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-sip-183-00). If it is your Freeswitch sending the 183 you do not want, remove `ringback=\'%(2000,4000,440,480)\` and see if that works. Also, you can use [`ring_ready`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+ring_ready) to send a 180 which should not have SDP/early media.